# Flutter html tags

Tags: html, flutter

I need to read the HTML codes in the page in Flutter. I found a package that does this, but there is a problem when opening some detailed SVG files. How do I read HTML tags within the page without using Webview?

I used the flutter_widget_from_html package. Overall it worked and did what I wanted. Problem displaying SVG files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the problem,
I downloaded the Core package and used flutter_svg for Svg files.

Answer (score 0):

The [fwfh_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/fwfh_svg) package is an extension to the [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html) to support rendering SVGs.

From the package's readme:

> WidgetFactory extension to render SVG with flutter_svg plugin. This is a companion add-on for flutter_widget_from_html_core package.

Comment: That package was made for flutter_widget_from_html_core. In the readme it says that I should use the flutter_widget_from_html package for SVG.

Comment: I believe it's included in the non-core package. You can follow the usage guide from the fwfh_svg API reference